# NameError: name 'PhotoImage' is not defined, dont know how to add image

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a background image to the window but I can't. I tried almost every way I know...

```
class main:
    def __init__(self):
        global lol
        self.rip = tk.Tk()
        self.f2 = tk.Frame(self.rip)
        self.f2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=("nwes"))
        self.f2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.f2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c1=tk.Label(self.f2, text="feet to meter or meter to feet?")
        self.c1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.c2=tk.Label(self.f2, text='type "ft" for feet to meter, type "m" for meter to feet')
        self.c2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lol = tk.StringVar()
        self.choice = tk.Entry(self.f2, width=7, textvariable=lol)
        self.choice.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.b1=tk.Button(self.f2, text="Confirm", command=choose)
        self.b1.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="bgmain.gif")
        tk.Label(self,image=self.bg).pack()
        self.pack(side="top")
```

The error message says:
`NameError: name 'PhotoImage' is not defined`.
How can `PhotoImage` not be defined???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PhotoImage` class is part of the Tkinter module, just like all the other Tkinter classes you're calling (`Label`, `StringVar`, `Button`, etc).  You haven't loaded `PhotoImage` into the global namespace, so you can't access it simply with `PhotoImage`.  Try `tk.PhotoImage` instead.

```
self.bg = tk.PhotoImage(file="bgmain.gif")
#         ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

`PhotoImage` is not in your global namespace. Alternatively to accessing it with `tkinter.PhotoImage`, you can import `PhotoImage` into the global namespace with:

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an image to the background of my app!
How do I do that?

class HomePage:
    def **init**(self):
        self.homePageWindow = tkinter.Tk()
        self.homePageWindow.wm_title("T")
        self.homePageWindow.iconbitmap(r'20.ico')
        self.homePageWindow.geometry("540x540+0+0")
        self.homePageWindow.configure(background='Gray')

```
    tkinter.Label(self.homePageWindow,font=('Titr',20),text = "t",bd=1,bg='Gray',fg='Yellow').grid(pady = 10,padx=10, column = 4, row = 1,sticky='e')

    tkinter.Button(self.homePageWindow, width = 10,height=2, font=('Nazanin',12,'bold'),  text = "Insert",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command = self.Insert).grid(pady = 14,padx=14,column =4, row = 2)
    tkinter.Button(self.homePageWindow, width = 10,height=2,font=('Nazanin',12,'bold'),  text = "Update",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command = self.Update).grid(pady = 10,padx=14,  column = 5, row = 3)
    tkinter.Button(self.homePageWindow, width = 10,height=2, font=('Nazanin',12,'bold'), text = "Search",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command = self.Search).grid(pady = 10,padx=7, column = 3, row = 5)
    tkinter.Button(self.homePageWindow, width = 10,height=2,font=('Nazanin',12,'bold'),  text = "حذف",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command = self.Delete).grid(pady = 10,padx=7, column = 3, row =3)
    tkinter.Button(self.homePageWindow, width = 10,height=2,font=('Nazanin',12,'bold'),  text = "Display",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command = self.Display).grid(pady = 12,padx=7, column = 4, row = 8)
    tkinter.Button(self.homePageWindow, width = 10,height=2,font=('Nazanin',12,'bold'), text = "Exit",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command =  self.homePageWindow.destroy).grid(pady = 10,padx=7, column = 5, row = 5)


    self.homePageWindow.mainloop()

def Insert(self):
    self.insertWindow = InsertWindow()

def Update(self):
    self.updateIDWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    self.updateIDWindow.wm_title("Update")


    self.id = tkinter.StringVar()


    tkinter.Label(self.updateIDWindow, text = "id ?", width = 50).grid(pady = 20, row = 1)


    self.idEntry = tkinter.Entry(self.updateIDWindow, width = 5, textvariable = self.id)

    self.idEntry.grid(pady = 10, row = 2)


    tkinter.Button(self.updateIDWindow, width = 20, text = "update",bd=3,bg='brown',fg='yellow', command = self.updateID).grid(pady = 10, row = 3)

    self.updateIDWindow.mainloop()

def updateID(self):
    self.updateWindow = UpdateWindow(self.idEntry.get())
    self.updateIDWindow.destroy()

def Search(self):
    self.searchWindow = SearchDeleteWindow("Search")

def Delete(self):
    self.deleteWindow = SearchDeleteWindow("Delete")

def Display(self):
    self.database = Database()
    self.data = self.database.Display()
    self.displayWindow = DatabaseView(self.data)
```

homePage = HomePage()